# What is the difference between 'su -' and 'su root'?

Tags: permissions, root, su

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do we use su - and not just su?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7013/why-do-we-use-su-and-not-just-su)

I understand that root [doesn't have to be a superuser](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10956/what-is-the-difference-between-root-and-superuser/10957#10957). But in the case that it is ... what is the difference between `sudo su -` and `sudo su root`?

Comment: Never mind google or the man pages, did you search this site for duplicate questions before you asked? The topic is covered [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7013/1925), [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7911/1925) and [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/15030/1925) as well as in passing in a number of questions about the usage of `sudo`.

Comment: @Caleb - I found that question before posting, but that did not answer my direct question. See the second part of @Mat's answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are two questions there:

- Difference between `su - username` and `su username`

If `-` (or `-l`) is specified, `su` simulates a real login. The environment is cleared except for a few select variables (`TERM` notably, `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` on some systems). Otherwise the environment is left as it is except for `PATH` that is reset.

- Difference between passing no user name and specifying `root`

This might be system-dependent. On Linux with [`shadow`](http://pkg-shadow.alioth.debian.org/) as the package providing `su`, if no username is specified, then `su` first tries to see if user `root` has a `passwd` entry. If it does, it uses that. If it doesn't, it tries `uid` 0.

Not sure about other Unix-like operating systems.

Answer (score 8):

`su -` switches to the superuser and sets up the environment so that it looks like they logged in directly. `su root` switches to the user named root and *doesn't* simulate directly logging in.

If the superuser is named root, then `su` and `su root` are equivalent (and don't simulate directly logging in), as are `su -` and `su - root` (which do).