# What is the use of "sudo -l" command

Tags: sudo, root

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10956/420113) link here mentions there is no difference between super-user and root user and according to the man page of sudo

```
 -l, --list  If no command is specified, list the allowed (and forbidden)
             commands for the invoking user (or the user specified by the
             -U option) on the current host.  A longer list format is used
             if this option is specified multiple times and the security
             policy supports a verbose output format.
```

If we specify no command and use `-l` flag, it is supposed to give us a list of allowed and forbidden commands for the invoking user. But when I tried this as a non-root user, it gives me an error saying.

> Sorry, user parasite may not run sudo on playbox.

I'm unable to run this command as any non-root user but if I can't run this command being a non-root user, what is it used for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, exactly as it says: list the allowed (and forbidden) commands for the invoking user. You are able to run `sudo -l` and this it what it tells you.

In your case: the user `parasite` is not allowed to run any sudo commands. If you try `sudo id` you'll get a message:

```
parasite is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

On my system, I get from `sudo -l`:

```
User bigboss may run the following commands on verlaine:
   (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

If you want to enable `parasite` to run sudo commands, you must add him to the `sudoers` file. Typically, you would run `visudo` as root to do this.